# Photoshop JS select contents of layer?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

1. Is there a method in photoshop that selects all pixels on targeted layer? (Mac-Command) click on thumbnail in layer window). If not....
2. I did have a working version of this, but somewhere along the lines Photoshop has updated it's commands and the snippet no longer works.
   That script was full of dragons and when I run it today in Photoshop CC 2017 I get the following error [image]

Here's the snippet :

```
//setCurrentLayerSelection. Ton's of 'here be dragons::
            var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );

            var actionSelect = new ActionReference();
            actionSelect.putProperty( idChnl, charIDToTypeID( "fsel" ) );

            var actionTransparent = new ActionReference();
            actionTransparent.putEnumerated( idChnl, idChnl, charIDToTypeID( "Trsp" ) );

            var actionDesc = new ActionDescriptor();
            actionDesc.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "null" ), actionSelect );
            actionDesc.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "T   " ), actionTransparent );

            executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "setd" ), actionDesc, DialogModes.NO );
```

The line that breaks is the very last line.
Is there a quick fix for this, or even better, a standard method? It seem to me as a very basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I can only find an answer to #2, but here goes :

1. Get the photoshop ScriptinListener.plugin
   download here : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html
2. (for mac) put the plugin in the Plug-ins folder (subfolder of 'Adobe Photoshop CC 2017')
3. Start photoshop (or restart if currently open)
4. Do the user action that you want to capture.
5. On your Desktop (Mac again) there's a file called ScriptingListenerJS.log. It contains all the recorded actions in javascript. Not sexy, but worked for me.
6. Note, once you're done recording, you might want to remove the plugin, as it'll always write to the log file and is a waste of resources if you're not using it.